# REST API returns different results based on the base URL

Tags: rest-api, describesobject

**Problem:**

Hitting the REST API from JS (inside a VF page) seems to be returning and old (or cached) version of the page layout.

**Examples:**

`https://eu6.force.com/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Contact/describe/layouts/012000000000000AAA`

returns the updated page layout. Adding a field or two, or even changing sections on the layout are appropriately represented in the response from the aforementioned URL. However, if I hit the following URL (note the vf subdomain):

`https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Contact/describe/layouts/012000000000000AAA`

it returns the original page layout before my changes. Same SessionID is used for both calls.

**Question:**

Is this some sort of caching problem on the Salesforce side or is there something else that I'm missing here?

Comment: Does the subdomain URL layout response eventually change to the expected value?

Comment: A bit of a reach, but are there any [ETag's or conditional headers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_conditional_requests.htm)?

Comment: I just hit the API today again with a new session Id - both responses matched. Then I changed the layout again, got the old response from both endpoints... It smells like cookies and invalidating cache issue to me

Comment: I wonder if it is just the layouts that appeared to be cached or if other metadata would have the same problem.  E,g, a straight `/Contact/describe/`.

Comment: I will need to do some more investigation on this tonight...

Comment: Does appending a cachebuster param help? e.g   /sobjects/Contact/describe/layouts/012000000000000AAA?cb=<some timestamp>

Comment: That didn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce does seem to cache the layouts, and the behaviour varies for some reason between end points (could just be load balancing?).

Either way, adding a `Cache-Control` header to the request, with the value `no-cache` fixes the issue.